# How to fix sonar issues automatically using rules or without rule

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I would like to work on sonar issues with automatic fixes (**using rules or without rules)**.

**Below are the steps I used, but no output!**

1. I got reference from [this](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java) github repository
2. I followed all the steps, but my code doesn’t have the below-commented lines.
3. How can I handle this problem? I am struggling with these steps.

**Example class:** I tried the simple remove toString() method in String class using rules

```
public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "hello".toString(); **// Noncompliant [[sc=17;ec=24;quickfixes=qf1]]
        // fix@qf1 {{Remove "toString()"}}
        // edit@qf1 [[sc=24;ec=35]] {{}}**
    }
}
```

1. Any feasible solution?
2. Any other possible solution?
3. How to work the fixes without **// Noncompliant**?

Comment: You should directly ask on their community forum -> https://community.sonarsource.com/